# How to check that iPhone is on or off status by swift?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am making experimental art installation about how much time people use their cellphone in unconscious.
And what I am focusing on is elapsed time from cellphone's on to cellphone's off. 
Now, I am using iPhone and trying to make app for this.

Is it possible to check by code?

Comment: I don't think is possible.  Even if it were, I'm not sure a phone's on-time is a very accurate measure of how much time the cellphone is being used.  I never turn my phone off... does that mean I use it 24/7?  How many people *do* turn their phone **off** with any regularity?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think I made you confused, sorry. What I mean is using power button. Pressing power button once for on or off, not totally off the phone.

Answer (score 1):

not with the public API.  There might be some way to do it on a jailbroken phone